# Firebase Project ID must be in lowercase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I'm trying to host a portal on Firebase.

I have currently installed Firebase CLI and when I load up terminal and type the following commande in the location directory that contains the project root folder I get the following error message.

```
$ init firebase 

Error: Invalid project id: XXXXXXXXXXX.
Note: Project id must be all lowercase.
```

My Project ID on Firebase is `grabcab-cd93e` so it is in lower case.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you typed "init firebase" and not actually "firebase init"?  Could you edit the question to show in more detail the output of the CLI?  Just copy what you see in your terminal, paste it into the question, and format it as code.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the error i faced in terminal - at this stage i had already recreated a firebase project to again removing all capital letter and hypens. LINK TO IMAGE: https://ibb.co/fQfrs9p

Comment: Apparently this happens if you type 'firebase use' into terminal or 'firebase use <name>' instead of firebase use --add.

Answer (score 3):

I got similar issue, and following page helps me.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2203
I open my ~/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json, and delete the line that project's name includes uppercase.
There should be the project XXXXXXXXXXX as you say.

Comment: After I had deleted my entire project and every other thing in sight firebase related, and still was encountering the error, this is what worked. Thank you.

Comment: As a new user to firebase, this location of firebase-tools.json is not clear. Is this on my PC or firebase somewhere? Where is ~/.config/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but in my case I have created branch in uppercase and while setting up firebase project for prod and staging, ProjectId accidentally happens to be in uppercase(firebase took the branchName for projectId), and since then I was getting this exact same error and then all commands fails,
`even firebase use --clear`.

This happens even if there is no `.firebaserc` file.

I am able to solve this using following these two commands.

```
firebase use --clear --project "ProjectName" (Cleared active project.)

firebase use --add (to define a new project alias).
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

1. Change the directory name of project in Angular (use name in lowercase)
2. Change the name project in all sites in the files angular.json and firebase.json
3. Execute  ng add @angular/fire and follow instructions